# React Navigation swap back and forth between two screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to preserve the state of two React Navigation (React Native) screens and allow the user to move back and forth between them, without the screens being remounted.

Using the example of two screens `A` and `B`, where the user navigates from `A` to `B` to `A`:

- If I use `navigation.push` the previous state isn't reused, my stack ends up as `[A,B,A]`
- If I use `navigation.navigate`, I lose the state of `B` when returning to `A`, my stack ends up as `[A]`

What I want is for my stack to always be `[B,A]` or `[A,B]`